# unsupported_grant_type error in angularJS and web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to achieve  user login
and logout using angularJS and web Api
But  the server always return badrequest (400)
exception

the error is coming from this bit of code

```
AuthApp.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {

   var  authServiceFactory = {};

    var _authentication =
        {
            isAuth: false,
            userName: ""
        };

    // this is the login function
    authServiceFactory.login = function (loginData) 
    {
        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;    //is not working

        //var data = { username: loginData.userName, password: loginData.password, grant_type: "password" };     // I try this and is not working too
        //data = $.param(data);
        // how should I format my data for the web API to understand

       var deferred = $q.defer();
       // alert(data);
        $http.post('/token', data, {
            header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (response) {
            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: response.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err) {
            // _logout();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    authServiceFactory.logout = function ()
    {
        localStorageService.remove("authenticationData");
        _authentication.isAuth = false;
        _authentication.userName = "";

    }

    return authServiceFactory;
}]);
```

using postman to further  see the error
this appears

> {   "error": "unsupported_grant_type" }

I made google search but still no solution; how can I resolve this issue?
thanks in advance!!

Comment: I cannot see any server-side code. Also, debug those kind of issue from the server or you will never be able to understand what is going wrong.